# Passing object literal styled component

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, styled-components, react-props

I have something like the following:

```
functionName = () => {
  const {
    prop1,
    prop2,
    prop3,
  } = this.props;

  const collectionOfProps = {
    'ONE': prop1,
    'TWO': prop2,
    'THREE': prop3,
  }

  return (
    <FirstWrapper>
      collectionOfProps={collectionOfProps}
    </FirstWrapper>
  )
}
```

In my `FirstWrapper` I have a function like this

```
const firstConst = ( {collectionOfProps} ) => firstFunction(
  collectionOfProps[ONE],
  hardCodedValue
)

const firstFunction = (value1, value2) => {
  value1 === something
    ? true
    : false
}
```

But I currently get the following console error

`ONE is not defined`

Any help on this would be amazing!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ONE` should be passed as a string. You seem to be passing `ONE` as a variable which doesn't exist in the scope.

So

```
const firstConst = ( {collectionOfProps} ) => firstFunction(
  collectionOfProps["ONE"],
  hardCodedValue
)
```

Comment: Oh yeah! *facepalm* Thanks! Guess it may be a good question for others to learn from

Comment: @zeduke You probably will be reminded of this in the future to come 